# How to generate new revision each build in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using vue cli with pwa (workbox).

every time I build the project vue is create for me file: `precache-manifest.882c44d211b70f8989278935.js`.

inside I have entries: `revision`, `url`:

```
{
    "revision": "2332b61ff6f66ba9523b370a7f21196d",
    "url": "/index.html"
},
```

If I don't change the file, it gets the same `revision`.

My question is how to force to have different `revision` each time I build the project?

Comment: I dont understand the problem, if you did not  change the manifest file why you want to change the reversion, because browsers cache it until you change it, and it is good approach for caching

Answer (score 0):

You may need workbox@v5 to modify the manifest.

Assuming using yarn, add `resolutions` field in `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {                      
  "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa/workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0"
},
```

Then run `yarn` to install. And in your `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {                    
  pwa: {                                
    workboxOptions: {                     
      exclude: ['index.html'],            
      additionalManifestEntries:[           
        { url: '/index.html',revision: Date.now().toString() }
      ]
    } 
  }                                 
}
```

See also:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5119#issuecomment-580144313
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2243

---

If you don't like workbox@v5, apparently you can modify precache manifest after build :)